# include mathjax in android app

Tags: android, mathjax

I am trying to include MathJax in my app. I removed files not needed for my app and brought down the size of the MathJax folder to 3Mb.

My mathjax folder is in the assests directory of my app. 
I tried to link mathjax using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
```

This does not seem to work.
Is my path to the mathjax wrong? Because my app worked fine when i gave my source as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
```

**Solution:**

W.R.T Paul's solution, here are the changes that i made

```
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({  
skipStartupTypeset: true,
config: ['default.js'],
jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
extensions: ['tex2jax.js'] 
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="file:///android_asset/antest_files/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Android you have to reference a little different:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Notice that you can't add the config parameter, as it won't load correctly. 
You need to make configurations using:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
...
</script>
```

More information on this post: http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498

Hope I could help

Comment: I am trying to include MathJax in my Ionic 2 App (offline). Please explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time a go, but I also had the same issue and I figured out that by installing the `cordova crosswalk webview` plugin, there is no need to change the way to load the MathJax script.

Just run:

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

And you are good to go!!!